# Some important html tags are removed in Odoo with the template engine jinja2

Tags: html, jinja2, odoo, odoo-14

I use **Odoo** and the **email template module** from setting (Odoo). I code my emails with the template engine **Jinja2**.

I paste my code with my style directly in the editor (black screen), but the "doctype", the "html" tag, the "head" and the "body" are automatically removed. The rendering is then different in the email clients and the responsive doesn't work.
Do you have a solution to solve this problem ? Thanks for your help

This is my code before :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" />
    <!--[if mso]><xml><o:OfficeDocumentSettings><o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch><o:AllowPNG/></o:OfficeDocumentSettings></xml><![endif]-->
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
            color: inherit !important;
            text-decoration: inherit !important;
        }

        #MessageViewBody a {
            color: inherit;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        p {
            line-height: inherit
        }

        @media (max-width:630px) {
            .row-content {
                width: 100% !important;
            }

            .stack .column {
                width: 100%;
                display: block;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #FFFFFF; margin: 0; padding: 0; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; text-size-adjust: none;">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="nl-container" role="presentation"
        style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; background-color: #FFFFFF;" width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="row row-2"
                        role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" width="100%">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
                                        class="row-content stack" role="presentation"
                                        style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; background-color: #144b52; color: #000000; width: 610px;"
                                        width="610">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="column"
                                                    style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; font-weight: 400; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; border-top: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-bottom: 0px; border-left: 0px;"
                                                    width="100%">
                                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
                                                        class="image_block" role="presentation"
                                                        style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;"
                                                        width="100%">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style="width:100%;padding-right:0px;padding-left:0px;">
                                                                <div align="center" style="line-height:10px"><a href="#"
                                                                        style="outline:none" tabindex="-1"
                                                                        target="_blank"><img
                                                                            src="https://dam.malt.com/rebranding2020/malt-logo/malt-red"
                                                                            style="display: block; height: auto; border: 0; width: 124px; max-width: 100%;"
                                                                            width="124" /></a></div>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table><!-- End -->
</body>
</html>
```

And after :

```
<title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <!--[if mso]><xml><o:OfficeDocumentSettings><o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch><o:AllowPNG></o:AllowPNG></o:OfficeDocumentSettings></xml><![endif]-->
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
            color: inherit !important;
            text-decoration: inherit !important;
        }

        #MessageViewBody a {
            color: inherit;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        p {
            line-height: inherit
        }

        @media (max-width:630px) {
            .row-content {
                width: 100% !important;
            }

            .stack .column {
                width: 100%;
                display: block;
            }
        }
    </style>

    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="nl-container" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; background-color: #FFFFFF;" width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="row row-2" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" width="100%">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="row-content stack" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; background-color: #144b52; color: #000000; width: 610px;" width="610">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="column" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; font-weight: 400; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; border-top: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-bottom: 0px; border-left: 0px;" width="100%">
                                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="image_block" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" width="100%">
                                                        <tbody><tr>
                                                            <td style="width:100%;padding-right:0px;padding-left:0px;">
                                                                <div align="center" style="line-height:10px"><a href="#" style="outline:none" tabindex="-1" target="_blank"><img src="https://dam.malt.com/rebranding2020/malt-logo/malt-red" style="display: block; height: auto; border: 0; width: 124px; max-width: 100%;" width="124"></a></div>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody></table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table><!-- End -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is how odoo process `html` files.
**odoo** have its own `head`, `header` and `html` tags in the page you are trying to make.
What I am saying is that whatever we designs is just a section of **Odoo page** and if you inspect odoo page you will see these tags already there, because whole page is loaded from *odoo cdn*

Solution to this is to write `html` of components in `<section> ... </section>` tag. So your `html` file will consist of just sections. and will look something like this:
[same code for odoo page or odoo module description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3VuK.png)

When you code like this it will look very ugly if directly opened. But will make proper sense as odoo page.
Odoo also supports `bootstrap classes`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Do you know another trick to use the <style> tag in the code editor ?  I know I can code with "inline css", but I can't do it with medias queries to make my email responsive. 

I don't think I can use Bootstrap's responsive because email is coded with tables. 
Thanks for your help

`<style> @media (max-width:630px) {.row-content { width: 100% !important}</style>`